# difference in predictions between model.predict() and model.predict_generator() in keras

Tags: python, keras, prediction

When I use `model.predict_generator()` on my `test_set (images)` I am getting a different prediction and when I  use `mode.predict()` on the same `test_Set` I am getting a different set of predictions.

For using `model.predict_generator` I followed the below steps to create a generator:

1. `Imagedatagenerator`(no arguments here) and used flow_from_directory 
   with `shuffle = False.`
2. There are no augmentations nor preprocessing of 
   `images(normalization,zero-centering etc)` while training the model.

I am working on a binary classification problem involving dogs and cats (from kaggle).On the test set, I have 1000 cat images.
and by using `model.predict_generator()` I am able to get 87% `accuracy()`i.e 870 images are classified correctly.
But while using model.predict I am getting 83% accuracy.

This is confusing because both should give identical results right?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: are you using same models and can you share your code as well.

Comment: Have you made sure that predict_generator() yields exactly one epoch? Since Keras 2 the generators are step-based (see fchollet's comment here https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/5818) so you might have a different number of samples in your predictions. You can also reset generators to make sure you always start with sample #0.

Comment: @petezurich I dont quite understand what you mean could you please provide a sample code?

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji I think it would be easier if you provided your code. :0) Right now we can only guess whats wrong. Apart from that: You can reset a generator with `your_image_generator.reset()` before you start to predict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@petezurich Thanks for your comment. Generator.reset() before model.predict_generator() and turning off the shuffle in predict_generator() fixed the problem

Comment: Great. I am happy that you could solve your problem.

Comment: @petezurich hey there seems to be a different problem with generators now. say suppose you have 7427 test images and you use a batch size of 16 in model.predict_generator. The output is only a vector of length 7424 and not 7427. Thus for it to work the batch_size must exactly divide the number of samples. thus for an input array of len 7427 you should use a batch size of 7 to get 7427 length array output from predict.generator()